# Pre-installed Android APK - allow Google Play updates with App Signing

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-source, android-app-signing

I wish to provide a version of my app to a certain vendor, so they can pre-install it on their custom ROM.

I could generate them a release APK of my app, but since my Google Play app is using App Signing, that APK will be signed with the upload key instead of the app key.
Which means - updates from Google Play will not work due to signature mismatch.

What is the common practice for generating an APK for pre-installation, and keeping it open for updates from Google Play while App Signing is in use?

One solution I found was to download the APK directly from Google Play, locate the file on a rooted device and use that APK as the pre-installed APK.
This looks like a hacky solution and I find it hard to believe that this is the intended common practice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what Google [suggests](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=e#best) in for such case:

> If you also distribute your app outside of Google Play or plan to later, you can generate the app signing key you want to use for every app store, and then upload it to Google when you opt in to app signing by Google Play.